# CRUD utility in IDE or JSP

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, netbeans, javabeans, crud

I am creating a CRUD app in JSP using Java Beans. I want to ask if there are any built in capabilities in IDE or any add-on to generate the CRUD functionality for a DB table automatically?

Like setter and accessor methods can be generated by the IDE.
I know we can get CRUD using lot of frameworks like Spring,but for a simple app is this possible using just JSP and java beans?

Comment: How does IDE came to know about your DB?

Comment: yeah that's why I am asking..

Comment: So, you would prefer an IDE that would generate lots of code for you, that you would have to maintain or regenerate each time your schema changes, rather than using a well-established, documented MVC framework that has been designed from the start to make your code as maintainable and concise as possible? Use an MVC framework.

Comment: @JBNizet I understand your point, but for an application where I have to use only JSP and java beans, then whether I shouls write queries my self for CRUD fucntionality..?

Comment: If some arbitrary rule tells you to avoid any reusable library that could help you, then you'll have to do everything by yourself, because IDEs won't bother creating code generators that nobody will use because everybody uses libraries and frameworks to do that (like JPA, Spring Data, etc.)

Comment: @JBNizetThank you, that was what I was trying to convey to this user,IDE never know about your DB and for this purpose we use MVC..

Comment: Not sue if it fits you bill. But take a look at Spring Roo.

Comment: I knew its possible in JSF with netbeans

Answer (score 5):

**Telosys** (http://www.telosys.org/) has been designed for this job (provided as an Eclipse Plugin and as a CLI tool)

It uses an existing database or a "text model" to generate source code (typically CRUD screens)

And it’s possible to customize the templates if necessary

There’s a stack of templates for Java web applications, it can be adapted if necessary

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of tools for this purpose, i added 4 of them that i previously worked with them.

1-[MyEclipse for Spring (ME4S)](http://www.myeclipseide.com/me4s/), this IDE has code generation capability based on database.

2-[Appfuse](http://appfuse.org/display/APF/Home), Full-stack framework for building web applications on the JVM, you can create CRUD applications very fast and easy based on many web frameworks that Appfuse provide. you can see these [demos and videos](http://demo.appfuse.org/demos.html)

3-[SpringFuse](http://www.springfuse.com/), Reverse your database structure and generate a full J2EE web application stack in seconds

4-[Spring Roo](http://www.springsource.org/spring-roo), Rapid Application Development tool with lots of plugins and features

Answer (score 0):

Here is a detailed example for [Generating a JavaServer Faces 2.0 CRUD Application from a Database](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/jsf20-crud.html)

I have worked the above example with    [Apache Derby - DB](http://db.apache.org/derby/) and Tomcat 7.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @velvs4j can we do the ssomething like this using JSP?
Through coding I can do that as well,I am in search of a feature or a plugin that can serve the purpose

Comment: need some kind of template to do this

Answer (score 0):

By simple jsp its not possible. You have to write your comman methods for CRUD and call that in your entire application. For every framework we should write these methods.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Spring Roo](http://projects.spring.io/spring-roo/), it scaffolds everything for you and doesn't create runtime dependencies.

It's really simple and useful for CRUD applications. It's more like an IDE plugin than a framework itself.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Spring Roo](http://www.springsource.org/spring-roo). It is a tool for generating java code, and can scaffold a MVC JSP site: http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html/base-web.html

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans can actually help you generate a Swing CRUD app for a table on any supported database (by supported I mean databases for which you have the appropriate drivers).
Simply click New Project --> Java --> Database Application. Follow the wizard to setup your database connection, tables you want to CRUD, etc and watch Netbeans generate the entire CRUD app (that you can then further customize). I used this (alongside MySQL workbench) to create a complete Contacts app in less than 10 minutes in a hackathon; the Netbeans community did a wonderful job on this.
If for some reasons Swing may not be appropriate for your project (you really want to do web stuff), you might consider using the **Grails** framework (its a Groovy framework, there are YouTube videos to jumpstart you on this in less than 45 minutes). After creating your domain models (entities, analogous to database tables), the framework has a thing called UI scaffolding that can be employed in generating the CRUD web UI for those domain models; its really cool stuff. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

[Spring Roo](http://projects.spring.io/spring-roo/) - CRUD code generator, it takes in database and spits out Java + AspectJ.
Start from this tutorial: [Beginning With Roo](http://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/reference/html/beginning.html).